# Getting the last 2 characters of a dynamic string

Tags: javascript, string

I need your help.

One thing that's always going to be known in my function is that my string will always have a -2 at the end.

ie.

```
var x = filenumber-2
```

I'd like to use an if statement to check if the string: -2 is attached to the string. If it is just return true.

Since the `filenumber` value will be a variety of different combinations its length will always need to be accounted for. But as for the the -2 at the end, it is a given.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple regex-based solution:

```
if (/-2$/.test(filenumber)) return true;
```

Using either the String [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) or [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) methods:

```
if (filenumber.slice(-2) =="-2") return true;
if (filenumber.substr(-2)=="-2") return true;
```

The `-2` in the method call means "start 2 characters before the end of the string".

Answer (score 1):

```
if(x.slice(-2) == "-2") return true;
```

Will this suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Use the negative operator of the slice method. It starts counting backwards from the end of the string, so it doesn't matter how long it is.

```
if(x.slice(-2) == "-2"){
  return true;
}
```

Or if you really want you could use its length and count from the start

```
if(x.slice(x.length - 2) == "-2"){
  return true;
}
```